# Chrome Extension: How to inject code code into a new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So let's say I want to inject some code to create a button on a new window in chrome (The window itself is opened via the extension's popup.js). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Depends on the URL. If it's an html file inside your extension then you don't need to inject anything - just load the script in that html like `<script src="file.js"></script`. If it's a web URL then send a message to your background script, which will open the tab, wait for it to load, then inject code, [example](/a/67244340).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use functions such as documnet.body.appendChild() instead of console.log() in foreground.js after opening files with the names I gave their names and filling them in this way. You can add whatever you want to the page this way.

background.js

```js
function as(a,b,c) {
       
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "foreground.js"});
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null,{file:'./style.css'})
        console.log(a,b,c+'asd')
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    as(tabId, changeInfo, tab);
});
```

foreground.js

```js
window.onload=()=>{
    console.log('ok')
}
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "plugin",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "background": {
        "scripts":["./background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":[
      "tabs",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
button{
    color:red;
}
```